# Laravel+Vue. Caching problems (actually, just reserved variable name)

Tags: caching, laravel-5, vue.js, reserved-words

I create Laravel+Vue simple REST API web-app.
In Vue component I have a method with an api request.
I simplified this to see the core of the problem:

```
phpValidate() {

axios
    .post("api/validate", self.programmer)
    .then(function(response) {

        console.log(response.status); 

    });
}
```

In the controller I have a method `validateIt()`, which handle this `"api/validate"` request.
It returns:

```
return array('status' => $status, 'data' => $data);
```

The `$status` can be equal to 200 or 422, depends on the input data.

The problem is that from some point, it began to return `$status` of 200 always.
Even if I delete all the code from the method `validateIt()` and just leave two lines:

```
$status = 422;
return array('status' => $status);
```

I still receive 200.
If I delete the whole method in controller, it gives an Internal Server Error 500.
So, the route and function name is correct.
When I put it back, I can write there whatever I like, it doesn't have any sence - it still returns 200!

If I use debugger, I can see that at the end of `validateIt()` method it returns 422.
But, when I get the response in `phpValidate()` I see again 200.
Unbelievable!

I tried:

```
npm run dev
```

and

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

doesn't help!

Also I tried to restart the server and use different browsers, doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not a problem of caching.
It looks like the variable name STATUS is reserved.
Doesn't matter what value you give to $status in the controller method.
The $status always contains the actual status of the request and you can't change it manually. Even if the method is empty it will return $status 200 because the request was sucessfull.

The solution is to use another variable name for your own data.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and to solve it add version where you include your vue frontend file,do it like this it will never cache again:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js?version='.date("ymdhis").'') }}"></script>
```

and you should make sure that your vue server is running use npm run watch or npm run dev